# Über die Wendung "viel Aufhebens machen" bzw. "viel Wesens machen"?

Tags: phrase

Wieso steht in der Redewendung "viel Aufheben**s** um etwas machen" das Wort Aufheben im Genitiv? Und warum ist *viel* nicht dekliniert?

> Um die enormen Mittel, die aus Europa an die Landwirtschaft abfließen, wird übrigens zu Recht nicht **viel Aufhebens** gemacht.

Comment: Hast du einen Beispielsatz in dem diese Redewendung verwendet wird?

Comment: Man macht übrigens normalerweise nicht *von* etwas viel Aufhebens, sondern *um*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Das ist eine Genitivform (*genitivus partitivus*) , die bei Mengenangaben von [oft unzählbaren] Substantiven verwendet wird, genau wie in

> Ich trank ein Glas [des] süßen Weines.

Diese Form nennt man *partitive Apposition*. Das Objekt des Satzes ist "ein Glas", "des süßen Weines" beschreibt das Objekt durch den Genitiv näher.

Der partitive Genitiv ist ansonsten veraltet und wird i.A. dadurch ersetzt, dass "der Wein" den Kasus des näher beschriebenen Substantivs annimmt ("ein Glas süßer Wein"), in solchen stehenden Wendungen hat er sich erhalten.

Zwischen "viel" und "Aufhebens" findet keine Kasusangleichung statt, weil die zwei Worte eben nicht im gleichen Kasus stehen:

> Er trank drei Gläser süßen Weins
>
> Wegen dreier Gläser süßen Weins war er betrunken